# Increase JMeter threads dynamically at runtime based on condition

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In continuation with the problem #1 stated here -
[Limitations in achieving a target JMeter throughput value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62514181/limitations-in-achieving-a-target-jmeter-throughput-value)

I want to increase #threads in JMeter at runtime when they've reached the max load throughput they can create while my application is still not stressed.

Scenario - I'm increasing the JMeter throughput at runtime using Constant Throughput Timer and beanshell script as described here - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime.

Test plan - Along with CTT as described above, simple threadgroup with initial fixed #threads and infinite loop iterations is configured. HTTP Sampler for GET call is used. No other timer or plugin is added in the test plan.

I tried using beanshell script in the following ways :

(1) to update "threadsNum" variable for #Threads in Threadgroup set as ${__P(threadsNum, 400)}. But at runtime looks like the variable gets updated while the actual active threads are not getting modified. Is it because of the CTT used in the setup or any other config required for this?

(2) using JMeterContext in beanshell script and trying to update using ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(0, ctx.getEngine()). But ctx.getThreadGroup() and ctx.getEngine() both are returning null. Any insight or reason for that?

Output from beanshell script execution (initial #threads set to 400) -

```
Connecting to BSH server on localhost:9000
Reading responses from server ...
BeanShell 2.0b6 - by Pat Niemeyer (pat@pat.net)
Setting property 'req_per_min' to '6000'.
Setting property 'threadsNum' to '500'.
ctx.getThread(): null
ctx.getThreadGroup(): null
ctx.toString(): org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext@1a12992
ctx.getEngine(): null
Active Thread: 400
Started Thread: 400
... disconnected from server.
```